# How do I use awk to create an index of words in file?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a problem with my homework I need to create a shell script using `awk`. The script will output only the words in the file in an alphabetical order, and after the word is `:` after that a space then a comma-separated list of the lines on which the word appears. For example:

```
C
CB
92A 
A
BFG How Are You 
B Are 
C 
C Are
.
.B
```

It should be

```
A: 3, 4
Are: 5, 6, 8
B: 6, 10
BFG: 5
C: 1, 7, 8
CB: 2
How: 5
You: 5
```

I have tried this, but it did not work

```awk
#!/bin/awk -f
{
split($0, char);
print $0;
sort;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ awk '
{
  gsub(/[^[:alpha:] ]/,"");
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    a[$i] = a[$i] ? a[$i]", "FNR : FNR;
  }
}
END {
  for (i in a) {
    print i": "a[i];
  }
}' file | sort 
A: 3, 4
Are: 5, 6, 8
B: 6, 10
BFG: 5
C: 1, 7, 8
CB: 2
How: 5
You: 5
```